# how to get text area empty automatically when user click anywhere on the page. Angularjs, Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm working in angularjs project, I have one text area which gives me some result on search.I want my text area to be cleared whenever i click anywhere on the page.My code is

```
<input type="text" ng-model="bigdata" ng-change="ctrl.getData(bigdata);searchDataC =true;" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" placeholder="Search contacts" class="search-input ip-size-roster ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" aria-invalid="false" style="">
```

Comment: you can use the `ng-blur` directive with a function to do whatever you want Ex.`ng-blur="ctrl.clearData()"`

Comment: @FabioG let me check and will get back to you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery somewhere in project then you can use this.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').click(function(){
debugger 
 
var check= $('#text').val();
if(check!=""){
$('#text').val('')

}
});
});
</script>
<body">

<div class="table-responsive container" style="background:cyan; height:100px">
<input type="text" id="text" ng-model="bigdata" ng-change="ctrl.getData(bigdata);searchDataC =true;" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" placeholder="Search contacts" class="search-input ip-size-roster ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" aria-invalid="false" style="">

  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Click on DIV anywhere.

Comment: Using of JQuery with angularjs is not a good practise though I haven't use but thanks for you reply. If possible then will implement this. Code is exact what I expected :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="bigdata" ng-change="ctrl.getData(bigdata);searchDataC =true;" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" placeholder="Search contacts" class="search-input ip-size-roster ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" aria-invalid="false" ng-blur="clear()">



</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";

    $scope.clear = function(){
    $scope.bigdata="";
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

working link in w3school
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FCK88MIMAKGW

Answer (score 0):

you should use ng-click="reset1()" where you want to perform click event.

//html

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-click="reset1()">
    <textarea id="textarea" ng-model="txt">

    </textarea>

   <div>{{txt}}</div>

<!--<button id='btn' ng-click="txt=''">Reset textarea</button>-->
    <button id='btn'>Reset textarea</button>
</div>


//js

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.txt='';

    $scope.reset1 = function() {
        $scope.txt = '';
    };
}]);
```

Comment: let me implement then will get back to you.

Comment: My motto is text box get automatically empty whenever i click anywhere in the page. You have given click button. and Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

In Html File

```
app.factory('clickAnywhereButHereService', function($document){
  var tracker = [];

  return function($scope, expr) {
    var i, t, len;
    for(i = 0, len = tracker.length; i < len; i++) {
      t = tracker[i];
      if(t.expr === expr && t.scope === $scope) {
        return t;
      }
    }
    var handler = function() {
      $scope.$apply(expr);
    };

    $document.on('click', handler);

    // IMPORTANT! Tear down this event handler when the scope is destroyed.
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
      $document.off('click', handler);
    });

    t = { scope: $scope, expr: expr };
    tracker.push(t);
    return t;
  };
});
app.directive('clickAnywhereButHere', function($document, clickAnywhereButHereService){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      var handler = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      };
      elem.on('click', handler);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
        elem.off('click', handler);
      });

      clickAnywhereButHereService(scope, attr.clickAnywhereButHere);
    }
  };
});
```

In controller file

```
$scope.clickedSomewhereElse = function () {
    //clear text here
};
```

Comment: let me implement then will get back to you